# Chef's install error

Tags: chef-infra

I got an error while debugging chef-solo.

I can see same kind of problem like `....in 'from_file` when I install nginx via chef-recipes. I have downloaded and installed `epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm`, I have also created `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`.

What shall I do for this?

```
* package[vim] action install
* No version specified, and no candidate version available for vim
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[vim]'
================================================================================


Chef::Exceptions::Package
-------------------------
No version specified, and no candidate version available for vim


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /root/Development/chef-repo/site-cookbooks/vim/recipes/default.rb

  9: package "vim" do
 10:   action :install
 11: end
 12:



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /root/Development/chef-repo/site-cookbooks/vim/recipes/default.rb:9:in `from_file'

package("vim") do
  action [:install]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  package_name "vim"
  cookbook_name :vim
  recipe_name "default"
end
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually,It seemed to be installed.
If I try nginx -t ,I found some error and I fiexed,
then this chef's recipe started work without error.

Answer (score 0):

If I installed epel-package from rpm,it fixed and now I can run my recipes.

```
#
# Cookbook Name:: nginx
# Recipe:: default
#
# Copyright 2013, YOUR_COMPANY_NAME
#
# All rights reserved - Do Not Redistribute
#

yum_package "GeoIP"

yum_package "nginx" do
  action :install
end

template "nginx.conf" do
  path "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
  source "nginx.conf.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 0644
  notifies :reload, 'service[nginx]'
end

service "nginx" do
  action [:enable,:start]
end
```